# Aggregation doesn't work when writing classes in different files

Tags: c++, header-files

I have 2 classes written in 2 different files: router.h - router.cpp and topology.h - topology.cpp.

I will show the contents of the .h files because the .cpp ones contain only implementations.

router.h:

```
#ifndef _ROUTER_H_
#define _ROUTER_H_
#include <map>
#include "topology.h"

using namespace std;

class Router {

public:
    int id;
    map<Router, int> linkers;
    Topology topology;

    Router();
    Router(int id);
    void addLink(Router router, int cost);
    void delLink(Router router);

};

#endif
```

topology.h:

```
#ifndef _TOPOLOGY_H_
#define _TOPOLOGY_H_
#include "router.h"

class Topology {
public: 
    map<Router, int> graph;  
    Topology();
    void addNode(Router router, int cost);
    void delNode(Router router);
};

#endif
```

My question is, why at compilation I have an error that is caused by the unrecognized Router and Topology classes, even if I included the headers and I added ifndefs in order to not include files more than one?? I looked up on the internet, on stack also and didn't find anything about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this code is that your Topology (Topology.h) uses Router objects passed by value: the compiler needs to have the full definition of Router. That's fine, so you include Router.h.
However, your Router needs a full Topology object (not a pointer, not a reference) to work.

So you have a configuration where A needs B fully declared to be fully declared, and B needs A fully declared to be fully declared itself. That's a problem, as stated in comments, of Circular Dependencies.

What you should do is to avoid the Topology object in Router (you may need a pointer because a full object means copy and not shared instance). Use a forward declaration of Topology in Router.h (and `#include "Topology"` in Router.cpp) and declare your "topology" attribute as pointer/smart pointer/reference.

Comment: There's no need to use replace the `Topology` member. The circular dependency can be fixed by simply forward declaring `Router` in `topology.h` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`router.h` includes `topology.h` which skips including `router.h` due to include guards and then uses class `Router` in its definition which is not defined. The standard solution is to forward declare types (such as `class Router;`). Unfortunately `std::map` requires full types and using it with incomplete types is undefined behavior. To make the map compatible with incomplete types you can either use `std::unique_ptr<map<Router, int>>` (or some other pointer type) or [`boost::container::map<Router, int>>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/container/map.html).